# Android Firebase Username Login

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebasesimplelogin

Referencing the fire recent documentation , it was quite simple to use the email and password login system. However in order to increase user retention in app, I wish to allow usernames and passwords instead of email.

Can the Firebase email and password login be reconfigured to use usernames and passwords instead?